# How to call an extern C function from .so file in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin, shared-libraries, dllimport

I got this function, it returns -1 and prints something,

C++

```
extern "C" int CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface(int id)
{
    int result = -1;
    printLog("UCPlayer CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface called.");
    if (UCPlayer_UnsetSurface)
    {
        // TODO: Unset Surfice 
    }
    return result;
}
```

I compile it for armeabi-v7a, and get the libCsWrapper.so file

Then I go into VisualStudio 2019, make a Xamarin project, make a libs folder, in it i make the armeabi-v7a folder, and there I place the libCsWrapper.so file

In the MainActivity.cs

In the OnCreate function, I made a button to call the testCsWrapper function, this:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1).Click += (e, o) => TestCsWrapper();
```

And I got this bellow :

```
 #if Android
                const string DllName = "libCsWrapper.so";
    #else
                const string DllName = "__Internal";
    #endif

    [DllImport(DllName, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface")]
     static extern int CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface(int id);     

    private void TestCsWrapper() {
        try
        {
            int b = CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface(4);  // System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'
            Log.Info("STF", "Wrapper should return -1, Wrapper returned: " + b);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("STF", "Type: " + e.GetType().ToString() + " Message:" +  e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And it throws this error when I run it on my adb device:

```
Type: System.EntryPointNotFoundException Message:CsWrapper_UCPlayer_UnsetSurface assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
```

How can that be, if I got the extern "C" in the functions annotations?

Edit 1: I followed this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/#creating-the-internal-wrapper-class

I hope You can help me, anyway, thank you for Your time.

Comment: Files to be exported from dll should be declared with __declspec(dllexport). Is your .so a true dll?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the define `Android` set ?

Comment: @armagedescu this isn't a Windows DLL

Comment: @armagedescu this is a Linux .so file, not a windows dll

Comment: @SushiHangover If you mean if I set the: 'Conditional compilation symbols' to Android? then yes, I was following this site(sEE: wRAPPING NATIVE LIBRARY(STAGE 2) Step 19 and 20): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/#creating-the-internal-wrapper-class

Comment: @Elydasian Now anything update? Do you solve your issue now?

Comment: @Cherry Bu currently, it's onhold, I got a more urgent task right now